# Touchpad issues Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: touchpad

After switching from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu (as a dual boot) ,I found that the touchpad doesn't work on my Ubuntu, but does on Windows.
Please if someone could have a solution for this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install [xserver-xorg-input-synaptics](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics)
?

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Comment: This package is installed by default.